# SetFileInformationByHandle with IO priority not working well

Tags: windows, io

I want to set the file IO to low Priority without change the thread priority, So I use SetFileInformationByHandle like below:

```
FILE_IO_PRIORITY_HINT_INFO priorityHint;
priorityHint.PriorityHint = IoPriorityHintVeryLow;

bool result = SetFileInformationByHandle(desHandle,
    FileIoPriorityHintInfo,
    &priorityHint,
    sizeof(priorityHint));
```

And I Create File like this:

```
HANDLE desHandle = CreateFile(desPath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,     CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);
```

Each time I write 4kb data to desHandle like this:

```
while()
{
  ....
  if (!WriteFile(desHandle, startPtr, numOfEachWrite, reinterpret_cast<LPDWORD>         (&numOfBytesWritten), NULL))![enter image description here][1]
{}
...
}
```

But when I use process monitor to find only first 4kb data with low priority, all the other are with normal priority

Answer (score 0):

You probably should try noncached IO. In this case, your intent will be fully passed through to the underlying block level drivers. Priority is a hint after all.